# how to remain login after changing the password in Laravel 10

Tags: authentication, laravel-10

I am using Laravel 10 with Jetstream and one of my clients doesn't want to logout after changing the password from the Laravel default profile page. this is the default behavior of Laravel to logout after the password update. i have tried to re-login after updating the password like below:

```
$userId = Auth::User()->id;
$user = User::find($userId);
$user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
$user->save();
Auth::login($user);
```

but it throws the following error. i have also tried the Webguard which I am using but no luck

```
Auth::guard('web')->login($user);

Error: Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::login does not exist.
```

I have also tried this method

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user->id)
```

but I am getting the same error: Error:

```
Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::loginUsingId does not exist.
```

seems like the Auth facade is not working after the password updation

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. I get the reference from here [https://oluwatosin-amokeodo.medium.com/how-to-prevent-logout-after-password-change-using-auth-sanctum-as-the-middleware-in-laravel-3781ca46c1de#:~:text=Sign%20in-,How%20to%20Prevent%20Logout%20after%20Password%20Change%20Using%20auth,as%20the%20Middleware%20in%20Laravel&text=Allowing%20logged%20in%20users,user](https://oluwatosin-amokeodo.medium.com/how-to-prevent-logout-after-password-change-using-auth-sanctum-as-the-middleware-in-laravel-3781ca46c1de#:%7E:text=Sign%20in-,How%20to%20Prevent%20Logout%20after%20Password%20Change%20Using%20auth,as%20the%20Middleware%20in%20Laravel&text=Allowing%20logged%20in%20users,user))%3B%20does%20the%20trick.

```
        auth()->user()->update(['password' => Hash::make($request->password) ]);
        if ($request->session()->has('password_hash_web')) {

            $user = auth('web')->getUser();
            $request->session()->forget('password_hash_web');
            Auth::guard('web')->login($user);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Auth::attempt()` method. This attempts to log a user in using given credentials.

You can find out more here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: I have already tried this method but no luck.